# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cassandra.cluster'; 'cassandra' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, modulenotfounderror

I tried `pip install cassandra-driver`
inside pycharm terminal, conda command prompt in admin mode, I upgraded/degraded versions of cassandra-driver, restarted pycharm , created new env ,still showing error.

Here is my code .

```
import cassandra
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
```

my error massage:

```
C:\Anaco3.8\envs\FlipScap\python.exe 
C:/Users/Rushikesh/Downloads/FlipkratScrappingProject/cassan2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Rushikesh/Downloads/FlipkratScrappingProject/cassan2.py", line 1, in <module>
import cassandra
File "C:\Users\Rushikesh\Downloads\FlipkratScrappingProject\cassandra.py", line 3, in <module>
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cassandra.cluster'; 'cassandra' is not a package
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed), and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out).

Answer (score 1):

The error indicatest that the Cassandra Python driver is not installed.

If you haven't already, try installing it with:

```
$ pip3 install cassandra-driver
```

Check that the installation was successful by running:

```
$ python -c 'import cassandra; print cassandra.__version__'
```

If it is installed correctly, you should get something like "3.25.0".

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly same error.
In my case it was caused by cassandra.py file located at same folder of python code that I execute.
So you can see your error message telling " 'cassandra' is not a package "
I renamed cassandra.py and error had disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I think we can blame our dear DataStax for this, they mentioned Cluster with no camel-case and it cause this issue.

first make sure you have the package installed(`pip3 install cassandra-driver`), then use bellow code.

Just use it this way:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['172...', '172...','172...'])
```

Replace all the '172...' with your cluster IP set.

Comment: Error-ish info from DataStax: https://youtu.be/NKsRYoLhSJU